# Button displays text before radiobutton has been selected

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a button which (display's the text "Your critique has been saved") however it will display this text even if an option hasn't been selected. The options are the radiobuttons that are shown in the code below.

```
r1=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Cinema - Hoyts", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="Cinema - Hoyts", command=update_status)`
r1.grid(row = 4, column = 0,pady=15)

r2=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="TV  - Channel 7", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="TV  - Channel 7", command=update_status)`
r2.grid(row = 5, column = 0,pady=15)

r3=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Radio - Nova 100", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="Radio - Nova 100", command=update_status)`
r3.grid(row = 6, column = 0,pady=15)

l3=Label(frame_four, text="Rating Number:", fg='white', font=('Comic Sans',35, 'bold'))
l3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NW',padx=0,pady=0)

button_save= StringVar(entertainment_critique_window, 1)

def save_status():
    l2.config(text='Your critique has been saved')

button_save=Button(frame_four, text="Save Critique",command=save_status,width=10,height=1)
button_save.place(x=495,y=12,)
```

Comment: The only thing done inside `save_status()` is to update the text of label `l2`, so it is expected result.  Why do you expect another behaviour?

Comment: If you want `save_status` to update the button's text *only* if an option has been selected, you should check the value of `radiobutton_variable` first, e.g.: `if radiobutton_variable.get(): l2.config(text='Your critique has been saved')`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, I'm not really sure of what you are trying to achieve, but this example should illustrate how to use `Radiobutton`s and `StringVar`s with **Tkinter**.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame_three = tk.Frame(root)
frame_three.pack()
frame_four = tk.Frame(root)
frame_four.pack()

radiobutton_variable = tk.StringVar()


def update_status():
    l2.config(text=radiobutton_variable.get())

def save_status():
    if radiobutton_variable.get() == '':
        return 0
    l2.config(text='Your critique has been saved')

l2=tk.Label(frame_four, text="", fg='white', font=('Comic Sans',35, 'bold'))
l2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NW',padx=0,pady=0)

l3=tk.Label(frame_four, text="Rating Number:", fg='white', font=('Comic Sans',35, 'bold'))
l3.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='NW',padx=0,pady=0)

r1=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Cinema - Hoyts", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="Cinema - Hoyts", command=update_status)
r1.grid(row = 4, column = 0,pady=15)

r2=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="TV  - Channel 7", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="TV  - Channel 7", command=update_status)
r2.grid(row = 5, column = 0,pady=15)

r3=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Radio - Nova 100", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="Radio - Nova 100", command=update_status)
r3.grid(row = 6, column = 0,pady=15)

r1.invoke()

button_save=tk.Button(frame_four, text="Save Critique",command=save_status,width=10,height=1)
button_save.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='SE',padx=0,pady=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps, if I missed the point of your question, you can edit it or comment on my answer for clarification.